# Mocking a JSP's post method versus creating an API

Tags: java, javascript, forms, api

I have an requirement as per which I have to call an existing java function which is called  from the UI through jsp. Data is provided from a form.

I want to call that function from the java code.

Should I create an API which should be called from the java code, and pass all the parameters required for the java function

OR

create a mock of the form(if its possible) and pass it to jsp.

What is the recommended way?

Comment: If you have access to it as a library, do it like that--much faster. Otherwise use HttpClient or equivalent.

Comment: No, we don;t have access to it as a library but it is our own package. We need to put that package into dependency and use that if we want to call it as a function.

Is there any issue if we put it as a dependency and call it as a public java function?

Comment: You don't have access to it as a library, but you do? I have no idea if there would be any issues or not--don't know anything about your library or application, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is within the same Web Application, you may want to get a handle to that JSP via a request dispatcher, then call that with wrapped request/response objects, suitably tweaked to hold just the parameters the JSP needs.

Using `HttpClient` may lead you to all kinds of issues, as this would go all the way to the network layer (for starters: are you sure that you can connect to your own app from the server? Are you sure you really know the IP/port? Are you sure there's no login or session required? And there's no security filter that makes sure your request comes via the load balancer? And so on on...)

Going with an API (even going to the trouble of having the code exposed as an API with a code change) may look cleaner, though. But then, if you're already using REST or SOAP, then it may not be so difficult.